# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'uwu' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

Yo, I was tryna make something and lets say this is my code:

```
import threading
uwu = 0
def main():
    def e():
        if uwu > 10:
            print("no u")
            uwu += 1
        elif uwu <= 10:
            print('Hello, World!')
            uwu += 1
    done = False
    while not done:
        try:
            if threading.active_count() < 100:
                threading.Thread(target=e).start()
        except IndexError:
            done = True
            print("Done!")
            input()

main()
```

So, when I execute it I get this error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "ask stacc xd.py", line 5, in e
    if uwu > 10:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'uwu' referenced before assignment
```

If anyone could help me out with this please answer or comment.

Comment: Please **ask a question** when posting.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring global variable.
try with `global` keyword.

```
import threading
uwu = 0
def main():
    def e():
        global uwu
        if uwu > 10:
            print("no u")
            uwu += 1
        elif uwu <= 10:
            print('Hello, World!')
            uwu += 1
    done = False
    while not done:
        try:
            if threading.active_count() < 100:
                threading.Thread(target=e).start()
        except IndexError:
            done = True
            print("Done!")
            input()

main()
```